# What can one do as an individual to help support the development of skyhooks?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbit, astrodynamics, skyhook

In my recent research on the potential of a [SkyHook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyhook_(structure)), I've found a startling gap: it seems like no one is actively pursuing this technology. Many, including myself, believe that this could be the breakthrough needed to propel us among the stars.

**Quick Brief:** A skyhook, a theoretical structure extending from Earth into space, aims to enable spacecraft or payloads to rendezvous in orbit, using its rotation to launch into space or return to Earth without traditional rockets.

**Reasons for Immediate Development:**

1. **Space Access Revolution:** Skyhooks offer a revolutionary approach to space access, potentially reducing costs and logistical challenges associated with traditional rocket launches.
2. **Enhanced Payload Capacities:** Unlike rockets constrained by fuel, skyhooks could carry larger payloads, aiding materials, equipment, and personnel transport in fewer trips.
3. **Space Exploration Expansion:** Building skyhooks could enable more frequent and cost-effective space missions, facilitating enhanced exploration of the Moon, Mars, and beyond.
4. **Commercial Opportunities:** Easier space access could lead to a surge in activities like space tourism, satellite deployment, and microgravity manufacturing.
5. **Scientific Advancements:** Skyhooks could enable continuous access for scientific research, facilitating long-term experiments and observations currently limited by rocket launch logistics.
6. **Economic Benefits:** Despite initial investment, reduced launch costs and new space-related industries could yield substantial long-term economic gains.

I'm planning a website, akin to the Mars Society, to raise awareness about this technology. I hope to initiate discussions that push us toward a future amidst the stars. Any support for this venture would be immensely appreciated.

**Further Exploration:**

[Kurzgesagt Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dqwpQarrDwk)

[Kurzgesagt Sources](https://sites.google.com/view/sources-skyhooks/)

[History](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/isrn/2013/502973/)

[Interesting Article](https://medium.com/predict/skyhook-the-technology-that-could-challenge-spacex-3ed5fa84696f)

Comment: What is your question? Also it is well known that currently a skyhook is simply not possible due to the lack of suitable materials to build it.

Comment: @jfl That's incorrect. Skyhook proposals, unlike Space Elevator ones, don't require magic material. Current conventional materials that are already produced in bulk quantities could do the trick. See the HASTOL study for details.

Comment: @Dragongeek - while the first HASTOL study said "_Existing materials will do"_, the second HASTOL study expressed concerns that the proposed material is susceptible to being rapidly eroded by atomic oxygen. The study said (page 62) "_Coatings are currently used to protect surfaces on other spacecraft from atomic oxygen and UV, but unlike those surfaces, the tether will stretch and bend. It is unknown whether any existing coatings will adequately adhere to Spectra through many stretching cycles, and if so, how they might affect the overall strength to mass ratio of the tether system"_

Comment: @StevePemberton Well, sure, but keep in mind that the HASTOL study is almost *25 years old* at this point. A lot has happened since then, and while I grant that there are difficult technical challenges to overcome, I'd say they are the types of problems that are solvable with a reasonable budget and team of quality experts, unlike the problems associated with Space Elevator concepts. In fact, if I were NASA and had some extra budget sloshing around, it might be a good idea to do an updated study on a similar topic updated with today's tech and opportunities...

Comment: @Dragongeek - I agree and think they should also resume tether experiments, I think the only major test was on Shuttle in 1996 when they spooled out several miles of tether. It was for a different purpose, but still that's the type of skill that needs to be developed.

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your question is addressing this point:

> it seems like no one is actively pursuing this technology

I think there are multiple reasons for this

### It's too early for orbital-lift infrastructure.

Only in the past couple years has a major private/public interest in space re-emerged as it may have been present during the space-race and Apollo Era. I don't think it's unfair to say that this is almost entirely due to SpaceX. Regardless, we are *just now* seeing entrepreneurs starting to seriously consider space as a market and an opportunity that can be tapped, but we are still many years out from a space industry that doesn't rely almost entirely on government subsidy in some form.

For it to make sense to build infrastructure, there needs to be an active need for it, and, as it stands, we are still in the rapidly-climbing part of the s-curve when it comes to rocket technology. Right now, a F9 runs like \$1.5k per kg to orbit, and if the design and performance goals of Starship are met, I don't think it's unreasonable to drop this by a factor 10 to a blistering \$150 per kg.

This is so cheap, that assuming it pans out, it won't be unheard of for high-achieving high-school students to launch satellites into orbit as science fair projects in the 2030s.

Now, with costs reduced this far, it is likely that we will be approaching the limit of rocket-based Earth-to-LEO in terms of optimization. We've had airlines for many years now, and while there are still steady improvements, a 20 year old commercial jet isn't *that* different in performance to a brand new commercial jet. Sure, a couple percentage points here and there along with nicer and more comfortable features, but it is definitely a technology that has reached the top of the S-curve and requires a new breakthrough/paradigm to move forwards.

This is the point where a new system, like skyhook would make sense. Guesstimating, you could probably beat the efficient reusable rocket model (like Starship) by another factor 10, bringing the per-kg prices down to low two-digit dollar figures (\$15). Doing so however only makes sense if there is an enormous market demand for it, because infrastructure is *expensive*.

This is where going orbital costs about as much as a plane ticket does today, and a world where the *average human* goes to space about once every two years (right now, there's a world pop of about 8bn, and about 4bn passengers fly commercial every year).

We are still... many decades away from this.

### People are already working on this.

All that said, there are already scientists working on this. Not directly as skyhook, but working on elements that lead to it in the "technology tree".

Specifically, there have been many "tether"-based experiments involving small-sats and the behaviors of tethers in microgravity, which rather directly translate to skyhook tech.

Similarly, one component of the earth-to-orbit skyhook system is the spaceplane. Here, multiple groups are working on systems that may one day serve as a base or provide the engineering underpinnings for such a system like SNC with the Dream Chaser or the British team that's working on the SABRE engines.

There are also more general developments going on that lead to the development of more advanced orbital systems. One somewhat-shocking fact is that *there are basically no autonomous satellites* right now. Despite highly *automated* systems for eg traffic management systems, basically all LEO satellites today fundamentally rely on constant command/control from the ground to function. Some space startups, like Privateer, are trying to fix this by building the autonomous satellites that actually make decisions and operate independently in space, without relying on constant commands from the ground. This will also be critical in any form of advanced orbital infrastrcuture.

### Skyhooks are technically more difficult to understand.

This one is a bit "dumb", but one of the reasons why "Space Elevators" are as popular as they are despite being riddled with fundamental issues, is because the concept is dead-simple to explain. Everyone's ridden an elevator before, so if you tell someone you plan to build an elevator that's just really, *really*, tall, they more-or-less get it.

Skyhook, meanwhile, is much more complex. It requires at least a KSP-level of understanding about orbital mechanics (which is actually quite a bit) and a good grasp of high-school physics to even "get" the core concept (nevermind the more technical foibles). This makes it less attractive and more difficult to communicate.

If you'd like to start campaigning to address this lack of public knowledge about the topic or industry excitement about skyhook tech, go right ahead, but I think your energy would be better spent on fundamental science communication which brings ordinary people to the level where they could understand it to begin with.

Comment: *Doing so however only makes sense if there is an enormous market demand for it, because infrastructure is expensive*.  I understand, its really annoying how people are fighting random petty wars instead of coming together under one banner as humans. People only care about their next holiday instead of looking past earth and focusing on the possibility of conquering the stars. *It's too early for orbital-lift infrastructure.* I get its exspensive but after completing this project it would make the cost of space travel way cheaper.

Comment: There's also the demand-side argument - what would you even do in space if you could go there cheaply? 4 billion people fly a year because there are *reasons* for them to fly - business to conduct, friends and family to meet, sights to see. There's none of that in space unless someone pays even more to put it there. It would make launching satellites cheaper, but not enough to offset the enormous upfront and maintenance costs.

Comment: To say it's "too early" because the launch costs are now suddenly coming down by insane amounts just serves to help sweep competition out of SpaceX's path. This is unsubstantiated information in the face of several far more reputable sources of information that paint a very different picture.

Comment: @Candence good point. People may have no need to leave earth at the moment, but we must create those reasons. Eventually we will have colonies on different planets, Mars, the atmosphere of Venus. Other industries will move outer space for example asteroid mining. If we want to create a dyson sphere and harness the suns limitless energy we will ideally get to mercury. All of this is to be accomplished and SkyHooks are a step forward. We will never need this technology if we just stay on earth.

Comment: @Dino *Eventually*, yes, those might become valuable economic activities. But they're very, very far from fruition now and if you made a list of all the reasons why we can't (or don't) build a Dyson swarm or asteroid miner or Mars colony now, launch costs would be quite far down on that list. There are other, more tractable problems with more immediate benefits to solving them (such as reducing the amount of ground control needed for satellites as mentioned in this answer), and it would be prudent to tackle those first.

Answer (score 3):

As an individual: get a suitable education and devote your life to materials research.

When you've got something suitable look for commercial backing and lobby your politicians.

Answer (score 3):

There are a several things that you can do.

1. Help to raise awareness about the long-term value proposition of expanding human civilization out into space. A rising tide lifts all boats!
2. There's are people who are rightly cautious of non-traditional ideas because  of a few such ideas that don't really pencil out, yet never seem to die, and are tirelessly overpromoted by their proponents. So, demonstrate that *you* are different. That *you* have adopted a fail-fast mentality. Try really hard to avoid being painted with the will-never-listen-to-reason brush. This means *acknowledge* and *tackle* the hard problems head-on. Don't just make unsubstantiated aspirational statements like "This technology will one day deliver payloads at a cost of $10/kg."
3. Develop an open-source digital twin of your architecture. Put all of your mathematical analysis and due-diligence in it and upload it to GitHub. Wear it on your t-shirt, so to speak.
4. You should look for conferences that have sessions on space infrastructure or closely related topics. Then plan ahead: submit an good abstract well before the deadline, if your abstract is accepted write a high-quality paper, make sure that you provide a high-quality professional photo and bio that will help to support the credibility of the conference, then show up and give a well-rehearsed, engaging, and memorable presentation.
5. If you are able to give a good presentation then you might be invited to be interviewed by someone who has a successful YouTube channel or podcast. To be prepared for that, it's helpful to already have some at experience at being interviewed. It will help you to appear credible to the show's audience. You will probably have to do many practice presentations if you do not already have that kind of experience, or perhaps join Toastmasters to gain some relevant public-speaking experience.
6. More can be done to raise awareness concerning the true cost of the competition - that is chemical rocket launch. Rockets are both the essential trail-blazer and the long-term problem. People's expectation levels need to be set correctly or humanity will miss the opportunity to develop infrastructure when the timing is right. Launch costs is an area where there is plenty of hard data from NASA and other reputable sources - such as [a press release](https://www.nasa.gov/humans-in-space/nasa-awards-spacex-more-crew-flights-to-space-station/) that placed the cost of the Crew-10, Crew-11, Crew-12, Crew-13, and Crew-14 flights at \$1,436,438,446, which works out to around \$80,000 per kg. But, there's also a lot of misinformation in circulation and [circular reporting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reporting) is definitely happening. Look hard, find the ground truth, and use it to combat the misinformation.
7. Find people who are open to helping you out in exchange for you helping them out. Build relationships with these people. For example, ask them to review your paper in exchange for you reviewing their paper.

That's all I can think of for now - I wish you the best in your endeavors!

Comment: " a press release that placed the cost of the Crew-10, Crew-11, Crew-12, Crew-13, and Crew-14 flights at $1,436,438,446" – That press release doesn't say anything about the cost. It only ever mentions *price*, which makes sense, since SpaceX is a privately-held company, and thus the cost is a trade secret.

Comment: I would say the cost is what the customer pays and the price is what might be on the website or the sticker. It's like a new car or an airline ticket. When you ask "what did that flight/car cost you?" you are generally asking what the customer ended up paying in total.

Comment: Thanks for the post, this is very valuable!